# Should i call exit() in php to terminate execution

Tags: php

Should I call exit() in php to terminate execution of program if query conditions are not true

Comment: Calling `exit` at that point will immediately terminate all execution. So whatever code you have written after that won't be interpreted at all. You could just revert back through an `else` statement that the there is no match.

Comment: Maybe query conditions - are mysql query conditions? In any case it's better to tell the user that there are errors instead of silently exiting without any message.

Comment: Actully i want to terminate all execution..beacause In query i will get user authority.If that user dont have rights to open this page then i want to  terminate all execution of program

Comment: If your script is dealing with actual visitors - then before terminating the execution it is good to output some message or render a template. Even if there is an error - user should see something instead of blank page.

Comment: if you use the **return;** it ends from that point as an alternative to **exit()**

Comment: You may want to redirect the user to a login or registration page if they don't have the required access rights instead of exiting without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your circumstances. In some cases an `if`/`else` statement may be more suitable than `exit()`.

```
if ($query_condition_true) {
  // Allow Access - Show Resource

} else {
  // Deny Access - Redirect to Login Page
  header('Location: /login');
  exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use exit() or die() to terminate the current script and stop execution.

https://www.php.net/exit

Answer (score 0):

The exit() function prints a message and exits the current script. you can use it wherever you want to stop execution of a script regardless of any query conditions you give.
This function is an alias of the die() function. the below example will print a message 
 it can be called with or without function call parentheses.

```
    exit(message);
// --- 
    exit;
```

you can call exit() to stop execution , but it depends on your requirement. if you are using an if condition, then by default the code inside the if condition will not get executed if the if condition is not true. you can write an else condition to continue execution or the execution stops if there is no more code to execute after.

Answer (score -1):

No, you could do anything after any query condition.

Comment: Are you going to brief up or what ?